# is it possible to adjust Google Chrome icon size?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

is it possible to adjust icon size?

for example icon image size is 28X28 Pixels when you install new program

(top and right side of chrome browser, like google mail checker icon, google voice icon)

But our program icon size more bigger than current icon size. like 56X28 Pixels

so can we adjust image size?

Comment: Please be more specific.  Do you mean the toolbar button for a Chrome extension?

Comment: yeah toolbar button for a chrome extension :)

Comment: I highly doubt that's possible.  You should create a square icon.

Comment: One more question :) Chrome allow to add icon button on URL area. can we adjust icon size or not?

Answer (score 2):

No, the size is fixed. You can only make your image smaller so it can fit in it.
As [***the document***](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#icons) says,

> **Important:** Use only the documented icon sizes.

and there shouldn't be `28 x 28px` like you said.

When you install a new extension, the icon size is `128 x 128px`, and it is shrunk to `69 x 69px`.

The [***standard sizes***](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#icons) are:

```
"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
          "128": "icon128.png" },
```